# Uploading a file in MVC3 without using <input type="file">

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I am trying to click my action link and have it do the same thing that the  tag does.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Import Excel Document", "ImportFromExcel", "ExcelUpload",FormMethod.Post , new {@enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "btn btn-inverse"})
```

Basically I want to click the button and immediately pull up the choose file window and upon selection send that to the controller. I do not want to use the input tag if I can avoid it (does not style well with the outlook of my site).

Any suggestions?